# Allow Search for Invalid Date stored as string - Is it recommended or not

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables for an Entity - say Valid_Doc and Invalid_Doc. If document is valid, then all the data gets saved in Valid_Doc table.In case any of the attribute of document is invalid , it gets saved in Invalid_Doc.Due_Date is on of the column of both the tables. In Invalid_Doc , we are saving **Invalid dates as string**.

Suppose if user searches for documents through a SEARCH screen with following date

**Due_Date - is after - 07/07/11**,
Shall we show all the documents from both the tables.As Due_Date in Invalid_Doc  table is string, there is no way we can compare the entered search date with the dates available in database in **Invalid_Doc** table.

Can someone please guide me whether to use DATEDIFF - i.e. need to convert the String date in DB to **Date(millisecs)** first and then do the comparison with the entered data.Doing this , there may be unpredictable results. So , shall we allow the user to search for Invalid doc through Date or NOT.

```
Select * FROM   invalid_doc iil WITH (nolock) WHERE
CAST(Datediff(s, '19700101 05:00:00:000', iil.due_date) AS NUMERIC) * 
   1000 
   BETWEEN '1120501800000' AND '1120501800000'
```

Where '1120501800000' and '1120501800000' are Date converted in milliseconds.

Please suggest.

Comment: I think your main issue is to convert the string into a datetime first. So specify what you mean with invalid dates? You should split up the data and try make dd/mm/yyyy string to convert it after into a real date format, then after you can union join both tables and compare all.

Comment: Sorry , I was out, as I am populating the DB data by uploading an xml file. So, user can enter any date values , there is no validation, for e.g. 100/100/100 something.Do you suggest providing search facility for invalid dates or Do I need to add a check that if Date is Invalid , insert NULL

Answer (score 4):

I would convert the dates in the database to a uniform string format using regex (eg. Q20011231Q) and also convert the query to the same format before searching.
This way you would have control on your data and can easily  do comparisons

Answer (score 0):

I continue as answer :)
As I don't know your language you handle the xml data I strongly suggest you validate you date befor you insert into your database.
It is not possible to enter a non valid data value into a datatime field.

if you have a data like 11/24/2011 and insert it, the datetime value always add the time itself.
Then you have eg. 11/24/20011 17:29:00 000 as value stored.

If you insert less then a date it might crash or if the value can be converted to a valid date, the missing parts will be replaced by "current date information".

So in fact you have to validate you string, convert it. Something like this:

```
-- @datestring <= somehow your string from xml
SET arithabort arith_overflow OFF
SET @date = CAST(@datestring AS DATETIME)
IF @date is NULL SET @date = GETDATE()
SET arithabort arith_overflow ON
```

You turn overflow error mode off, try convert and set default if it fails.

Or in MS SQL

```
   IF ( ISDATE(@date_string) = 0 ) SET @date = GETDATE()
```

Hope this helps